# Wickedpicker jquery plugin shows behind modal

Tags: jquery, css, wickedpicker

i'm trying to attach a jquery plugin, wickedpicker, to a modal on my code, but it keeps displaying below the modal when i call up the modal. So is there any way this can be resolved just using css?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should use css but with z-index,
so for example if your modal is .moda {z-index:0} then you have to put your css wickedpicker like this .wickedpicker { z-index:200}

that will be a good solution, but remember to play first with css z-index, then you can go to your clases and add it

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp